# How can I check the last elements of a string and fix my code?

Tags: string, haskell

Decide whether a string is an identifier, that is, whether it starts with an uppercase or lowercase letter and all other elements are all lowercase, uppercase, digit, or underscore characters.

```
isunderscore :: Char -> Bool
isunderscore a 
 |a == '_' = True
 |otherwise = False

identifier :: String -> Bool
identifier (x:xs) = isLetter x && ( all isLetter xs || all isunderscore xs || all isDigit xs )
identifier _ = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a string. You use [**`last :: [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:last) to obtain the last element. But here you need to check if *all* remaining elements satisfy a certain predicate. This means that you can work with [**`all :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all). You can pattern match with `(x:xs)` to obtain access to the head and the tail, and then check with `all` if all elements of the tail satisfy a certain predicate, so:

```
identifier :: String -> Bool
identifier (x:xs) = isLetter x && all … xs
identifier _ = False
```

where you need to implement the `…` part.

Comment: I fixed it thnaks. I only get wrong result for one of my test case : identifier "Alma_123" == True . Do you have any idea what can be the fault ?

Comment: @Kopi12: you should not use `all` multiple times: otherwise you require that the tail of the identifier are all digits, or are all letters, you should write *one* `all` with a predicate that checks if that character is a digit, letter, or underscore.

Comment: identifier (x:xs) = isLetter x && all (isLetter || isunderscore || isDigit ) xs  I do not really understand what I miss in my code.

Comment: @topi12: use a *lambda expression*.